# JSF and links: the target property doesn't work?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I need to render a simple link in a page that open a pdf file in a new browser window.
I wrote the following tag:

```
  <h:commandLink target="_blank" 
       action="showPDF"
       title="Show attached PDF"           
       actionListener="#{bean.doShowPDF}"                      
       value="Show PDF">
         <f:attribute name="path" value="#{bean.pdfPath}" />
  </h:commandLink>
```

The target attribute seems to be ignored. The destination page appear over the current.

I tried with h:outputLink:

```
   <h:outputLink target="_blank" 
       title="Show attached PDF" 
       value="/visAttached.jspx">
         <f:param name="path" value="#{bean.pdfPath}" />
      Show PDF
   </h:outputLink>
```

but with the same result. The generated html , in both cases, has not the **target** attribute.

Where's my fault?
There is a better strategy in JSF to show a file in a new browser window?

Comment: It should work. What JSF impl/version? I vaguely recall similar issues in ancient JSF versions.

Comment: Tried it with latest [1.2_15](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html)?

Comment: Ouch!.. I'm using 1.2_08. Probably they've fixed it in later versions. I'll try.

Comment: Just tried with 1.2_15, same behaviour. I'll try with a simpler page (when my children are in bed...), my problem is in a very very complex page. Ah, I'm using facelets, can this be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `ice:` versions of them: [ice:outputLink](http://www.icefaces.org/docs/latest/tld/ice/outputLink.html), or [ice:commandLink](http://www.icefaces.org/docs/latest/tld/ice/commandLink.html). The [component showcase](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface) shows a working example (layout panels/collapsible panels has a lot of links, check the source):

```
<ice:outputLink target="_blank" styleClass="navPnlClpsblLnks"
               value="http://icefaces.org/main/home/index.jsp">
    <ice:outputText id="icefacesOrgLink" value="ICEfaces.org"/>
</ice:outputLink>
```